# Column total to reflect based on another column visibility

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a Total column which calculates the total of Owned, Out and Rented and perform as sum to get the Total (total column). I have added a Boolean parameter and added the visibility expression fr the Rented column. Now if the Rented column is not visible it should not account for that quantity in the Total Column. How can I do that? Will this be done via case statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using an inline IF statement. The condition is simple enough.

First off since you already have a boolean parameter to determine the visibility of the Rented column you can use that same parameter to determine whether or not to include Rented as part of the Total. There is no need to check for the visibility of the Rented column...that is unnecessary work.

First set your total column sum as an expression and check if the value is correct. Your expression should look something like this:

=sum(Fields!Owned.Value)+sum(Fields!Out.Value)+sum(Fields!Rented.Value)

I would then add in the IIF statement to conditionally include/exclude Rented from the Total based on the boolean:

=iif(Parameters!NameOfBooleanParameterHere.Value=true, (sum(Fields!Owned.Value)+sum(Fields!Out.Value)+sum(Fields!Rented.Value)), (sum(Fields!Owned.Value)+sum(Fields!Out.Value))

I have tested this using one of my own reports and it works. Notice that it wasn't necessary to check for the visibility.